# How to limit the input content to the EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-filter

I want to limit the EditText input content which just contains chinease chars, letters(a~z, A~Z) and numbers(0~9), it can't input any space char or emoji chars or symbols.

I have try to add a InputFilter to the EditText, but I am not really emoji unicode, and the result is that some chinease chars will be filted too.

Is there any other solution?

My EmojiFilter:

```
public class EmojiFilter implements InputFilter {

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart,
                           int dend) {
    if (filterSet.contains(source.toString())) {
        return "";
    }
    return source;
}

private static Set<String> filterSet = null;

private static void addUnicodeRangeToSet(Set<String> set, int start, int end) {
    if (set == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (start > end) {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        filterSet.add(new String(new int[] {
                i
        }, 0, 1));
    }
}

static {
    filterSet = new HashSet<String>();

    // See http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

    // 1F601 - 1F64F
    addUnicodeRangeToSet(filterSet, 0x1F601, 0X1F64F);

    // 2702 - 27B0
    addUnicodeRangeToSet(filterSet, 0x2702, 0X27B0);

    // 1F680 - 1F6C0
    addUnicodeRangeToSet(filterSet, 0X1F680, 0X1F6C0);

    // 24C2 - 1F251
    addUnicodeRangeToSet(filterSet, 0X24C2, 0X1F251);

    // 1F600 - 1F636
    addUnicodeRangeToSet(filterSet, 0X1F600, 0X1F636);

    // 1F681 - 1F6C5
    addUnicodeRangeToSet(filterSet, 0X1F681, 0X1F6C5);

    // 1F30D - 1F567
    addUnicodeRangeToSet(filterSet, 0X1F30D, 0X1F567);

}

public EmojiFilter() {
    super();
}
```

}

Comment: please share your code

Comment: @PhanVanLinh just add my emoji filter code

Comment: You want to limit your EditText to type only specified character set right?

Comment: Thanks all, I have use the regular expression to limit the content. [a-zA-Z0-9_一-龥]+